# Как добавить противоположную анимацию

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, анимация

Хочу сделать вот такую анимацию: https://dribbble.com/shots/3633228-Avanti-e-indietro-loader .

[image: анимация]

Но застопорился :( Буду очень благодарен кто поможет доделать анимацию (желательно доделать с помощью javascript/jquery)! Вот код:

```css
:root {
  --duration: 1.5s;
  --container-size: 210px;
  --box-size: 33px;
  --box-border-radius: 15%;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: var(--container-size);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; 
  position: relative;
  }

. {
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: -50% center;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
.:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange; 
  border-radius: 50%;
animation-delay: 5s;
}

.:nth-child(1) {
          animation: slide var(--duration) ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.:nth-child(1):after {
          animation: color-change var(--duration) ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.:nth-child(2) {
          animation: flip-1 var(--duration)  infinite alternate;       
}
.:nth-child(3) {
          animation: flip-2 var(--duration)  infinite alternate;
}
.:nth-child(4) {
          animation: flip-3 var(--duration)  infinite alternate;
}
.:nth-child(5) {
          animation: flip-4  var(--duration)  infinite alternate;
}
.:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: orange;
}
.:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
.:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: deeppink;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-color: orange;
            transform: translatex(0vw);
             box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: deeppink;
            transform: translatex(calc(var(--container-size) - (var(--box-size) * 1.54)));
            box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}
@keyframes color-change {
  0% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: deeppink;
  }
}
@keyframes flip-1 {
  0%,
    15% {
            transform: rotate(0);
             box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  35%,
    100% {
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
           box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}
@keyframes flip-2 {
  0%,
    30% {
            transform: rotate(0);
             box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  50%,
    100% {
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
              box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}
@keyframes flip-3 {
  0%,
    45% {
            transform: rotate(0);
             box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  65%,
    100% {
            transform: rotate(-180deg);
              box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}
@keyframes flip-4 {
  0%,
    60% {
            transform: rotate(0);
             box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  80%,
    100% {
           transform: rotate(-180deg);
            box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Что-то кода многовато. 2. А зачем тут скрипты?

Comment: 1. Я новичок в программировании поэтому столько кода, не знаю как сделать лучше. 2.Просто я думаю что сделать эту анимацию только через css трудно.

Comment: что за названия классов в виде смайликов?))))

Comment: @ThisMan, просто эмоджи.

Comment: @КаналCheata, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 4):

Вот вариант, только с таймингами и оформлением еще надо поколдовать...

### HTML

```
<div class="playground">
  <div class="boll"></div>
  <div class="ellipse">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipse">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipse">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ellipse">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
:root {
  --duration: 5s;
  --half-duration: 2.5s;
  --container-size: 210px;
  --box-size: 33px;
  --box-border-radius: 15%;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.playground {
  width: var(--container-size);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; 
  position: relative;
  }


.ellipse {
  width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg) rotateY(55deg);
}

.ellipse .circle {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.boll {
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: -50% center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: slide var(--half-duration) ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.ellipse:nth-child(2) .circle {
  animation: move-1 linear infinite;
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
}
.ellipse:nth-child(3) .circle {
  animation: move-2 linear infinite;
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
}
.ellipse:nth-child(4) .circle {
  animation: move-3 linear infinite;
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
}
.ellipse:nth-child(5) .circle {
  animation: move-4 linear infinite;
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
}


@keyframes move-4 {
  0%, 7.5% {
    background-color: deeppink;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  17.5%, 50%, 82.5% {
    background-color: magenta;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-180deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  92.5%, 100% {
    background-color: deeppink;
    transform: rotateZ(0) translateX(40px) rotateZ(0) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}

@keyframes move-3 {
  0%, 15% {
    background-color: tomato;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  25%, 50%, 75% {
    background-color: deeppink;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-180deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  85%, 100% {
    background-color: tomato;
    transform: rotateZ(0) translateX(40px) rotateZ(0) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}

@keyframes move-2 {
  0%, 22.5% {
    background-color: darkorange;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  32.5%, 50%, 67.5% {
    background-color: tomato;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-180deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  77.5%, 100% {
    background-color: darkorange;
    transform: rotateZ(0) translateX(40px) rotateZ(0) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}

@keyframes move-1 {
  0%, 30% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  40%, 50%, 60% {
    background-color: darkorange;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg) translateX(40px) rotateZ(-180deg) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  70%, 100% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotateZ(0) translateX(40px) rotateZ(0) rotateY(-70deg);
             box-shadow:  -6px -6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-color: deeppink;
    transform: translatex(calc(var(--container-size) + (var(--box-size) * 0.5)));
    box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: translatex(0vw);
    box-shadow:  6px 6px  rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  }
}
```

Смотрите здесь: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/1qdk94es)

Эллипсы позволяют вытянуть кривую обскока. Пример - [здесь](https://codepen.io/ghost028/pen/bEBKXZ)